# Extract a dictionary from a string with keys in curly brackets

Tags: python, string, dictionary, formatting

Is there a way in Python to extract a dictionary from a string which includes curly brackets, having the keys of the dictionary referencing the words in the curly brackets?

As an example:

'my name is {name}'

The method would return the following dictionary:

{'name':{}}

This would be to later use the dictionary and populate the string through parameters using .format():

'my name is {name}'.format(**{'name':'salomon'})

The all objective is to read a text file, put curly brackets around words I'd like to transform in parameters, load the text file and extract a dictionary where I can input the desired values to then reinject in the text.

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(re.findall("\{([^}]+)\}","my name is {name}, and i am {age}"))` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Similar [to Joran Beasley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76675535/extract-a-dictionary-from-a-string-with-keys-in-brace-brackets/76683477#comment135182998_76675535):

```
your_dict = {k:{} for k in re.findall("\{([^}]+)\}", "my name is {name}, and i am {age}")}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work quite well for my understanding of your application (just be sure to change the actions)

```
import json # Required
import re # Required

# Make a function for getFileContents
def getFileContents(path: str):
    lines = None
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        return file.read()

# Make a function to turn json file contents into dictionary 
# (you can modify this to return json.loads({any json string}))
def loadJson(path: str):
    return json.loads(getFileContents(path))

# Make a function to replace parameter with value
def replaceInText(textPath: str, jsonPath: str):
    dictionary = loadJson(jsonPath)
    keys = [key for key in dictionary]
    text = getFileContents(textPath)
    for key in keys:
        val = dictionary[key]
        text = re.sub("{"+str(key)+"}", val, text)
    return text

# Do anything with the replaceInText function
print(replaceInText('file.txt', 'jsonFile.json'))
```

Links:

[JSON parser](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20json.load,which%20contains%20a%20JSON%20object.&text=Here%2C%20we%20have%20used%20the,us%20a%20dictionary%20named%20data%20.)

[Key obtainment](https://sparkbyexamples.com/python/python-get-dictionary-keys-as-a-list/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20dictionary%20keys%20as%20a%20list%20in%20Python%20use,the%20form%20of%20a%20list.)

[Value replacement](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-with-in-a-string/)

Hope it works :)